# на странице продукта нужно вывести, доступные цвета данного продукта

Tags: php, cms, opencart

Добрый день друзья, подскажите как лучше реализовать такой замысел. На странице продукта нужно вывести, доступные цвета данного продукта(к примеру черный квадратик, синий, красный и т.д.), при клики на соответствующий блок(цвет) мы переходим на в карточку товара выбронного цвета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Договоримся, что вы используете чпу (SEO URL включено в настройках) и алиасы товаров у вас - это что-то из букав. А ещё немного разбираетесь в php и опенкарт.

Товар для примера - рубашка, алиас `rubashka`. Её цветовые варианты всегда содержат в алиасе название оригинала - слово-маркер(color) - цвет (`rubashka-color-white, rubashka-color-black` etc.).
Варианты цвета, естественно, добавляете через options, тип опции - image. Опции цвета всегда носят те же названия, что и окончание алиаса товара (`white, black`).
После этого необходимо внести некоторые изменения в файл представления `product.tpl`
Ищите в этом файле фрагмент кода, который разворачивает ваши опции(в примере это image):

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
  ...
    <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
```

Внутри этого цикла оборачиваете содержимое ссылкой следующего вида:

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>-<?=$option_value['name'];?>">
```

Эта ссылка будет состоять из текущего адреса + название опции, которое совпадает с окончанием алиаса товара.

Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
  <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>" style="flex-direction:column-reverse;display:flex;align-items:center;">
    <label class="control-label hidden-xs"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
    <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" style="display:table">
      <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <a href="<?=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-color'));?>-color-<?=$option_value['name'];?>">
        ....................................................................
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
              <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
              <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
              <?php } ?>
            </label>
          </div>
        </a>
        ....
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Если вы будете использовать опции других типов, то просто ищите их в product.tpl по аналогии и оборачивайте ссылкой как в примере. Так же обратите внимание на то, что такой подход ограничит вас в использовании опции типа image(либо того типа, который будете использовать), т.к. каждая опция такого типа будет оборачиваться ссылкой и использовать её по прямому назначению опции товара опенкарт уже не получится.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Вроде работает, но url ссылки кракозяброй отображается, думал установить модуль seopro для версии 2.2 но что то криво он встает

Comment: @Alan.Sh Кракозябры бывают из-за использования русского языка в урле. Проверьте, что бы не в чпу, не в названии опций его не было.

Comment: Сделал название опции на англ и seo url тоже на англ, но нечего не поменялось

Comment: Url заработал нормально, но теперь другая проблема. Во первых он выводит url того продукта на страницы которого я нахожусь и в конце к url он добавляет значение опции

Comment: @Alan.Sh Всё верно, так и должно быть. Каждый подтовар(товар другого цвета) должен иметь сео-урл такой же, как и у основного товара, но с добавлением к улру через тире цвета этого подтовара.

Comment: Если есть товар с алиасом tovar, и есть его разновидность зелёного цвета (как отдельный товар), то у зелёного товара алиас должен быть tovar-green. При этом и имя опции, которая будет перекидывать на товар зелёного цвета должно тоже называться green. И далее по аналогии

Comment: А вот как! Спасибо огромное, очень помогли!!!

Comment: Смотрите если я сначала зайду на продукт с url (tovar) и в нем отображаются опции других расцветок к примеру (tovar-black; tovar-white), все работает и отображается нормально. Но если я сначала зайду на продукт с url(tovar-black), то попасть на продукт с url(tovar) или (tovar-white) уже не получиться. Как можно решить данную проблему?